# Using function to create object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, object

I am trying to create a function to automatically create object and then alert its properties. However, there seems to be some problem as I cannot get the alerts on click of button. Can someone help?

```
<html>    

    <head>
        <script>
            var player = function (x, y, z, i) {
                return :{
                    firstName: x,
                    lastName: y,
                    quote: z,
                    salary: function (i) {
                        return (i + 3000)
                    }
                };
            }
            var Saurav = player('Saurav', 'Ganguli', 'Bengali Babu', 1000);

            function alertify() {
                alert(Saurav.firstName);
                alert(Saurav.lastName);
                alert(Saurav.quote);
                alert(Saurav.salary(2000));
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="alertify()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `return:{firstName`, the `:` should not be there after `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onclick="alertify()">Click Me!</button>
<script>
    var player = function(x, y, z, i) {
        return {                        // <---- remove ":"
            firstName: x,
            lastName: y,
            quote: z,
            salary: function(i) {
                return (i + 3000)
            }
        };
    }
    var Saurav = player('Saurav', 'Ganguli', 'Bengali Babu', 1000);

    function alertify() {
        alert(Saurav.firstName);
        alert(Saurav.lastName);
        alert(Saurav.quote);
        alert(Saurav.salary(2000));
    }
</script>
```